# cannot see website on ubuntu 16.04 :LTS

Tags: dns

I am relatively new to Ubuntu. I have an Ubuntu LTS 16.04 setup with apache. I have 3 domains. They are pointed to my Public IP address and I use namecheap dns service as I am on a dynamic IP address. When I attempt to contact any of my 3 domains, I cannot connect to them. I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT I have set up port forwarding on port 80 to my Ubuntu machine IP 10.0.0.111 If I type 10.0.0.111 from my windows 10 computer I can see my index.html page. But only my one website, not the other two. 
When I do a nslookup on my domains, it resolves to my public IP.

What am I doing wrong? I have been searching for help for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The domains if set up correctly will return your external ip address. If you are inside the server network, the namecheap will resolve to your external ip address, which is pretty hard to resolve if you reside inside your network where you will need resolve all your domains to 10.0.0.111 ip address. 
You have two options:

1. Contact your server from external network to check the domain name resolution and of course your apache setup for three different domain names.
2. Setup a local name service resolution within your network, which will resolve all your domains to the local lan address 10.0.0.111. This needs to be done on your router. If you use Openwrt, the configuration is pretty straightforward (use dnsmasq service together with dnsmasq.conf configuration file) - more on this can be found in Openwrt wiki. For other router firmwares  look into your router's documentation.

After you can resolve DNS correctly, this is to be done next:

If you have configured your Apache correctly, the web server will return pages you have set up for different domains, depending on what you type in the address bar in your browser. It is possible to setup multiple domains on same IP and server. I guess you have already done this.